# Angular 2 update data when another data has been updated

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have two `<select>` elements, one for the *Districts* and the other one for the *Cities*. I get the districts by calling the function `getDistricts()` from `ngOnInit()` function. So far so good.

I don't know how to tell angular to fetch the new cities to the cities' select element. I tried to do like in the code below, but I've got an error:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cities' of undefined
```

It happens of course because the `selectedDistrict` is undefined in the start.

---

This is an example of a district object. (it includes the cities in it).

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "name": "A district",
  "cities": [
    {
      "id": 59,
      "name": "City 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 60,
      "name": "City 2"
    }
  ]
},
```

district.service.ts:

```
import {Injectable}         from "@angular/core";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import {District}               from "./district";
import {HttpClientService}  from "../http-client/http-client.service";

@Injectable()
export class DistrictService {

    private districtsUrl = 'districts/all';

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClientService) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    getDistricts(): Promise<District[]> {
        return this.httpClient.get(this.districtsUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().data)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    getDistrict(district: string): Promise<District> {
        return this.getDistricts()[district];
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

view-search.component.ts:

```
export class ViewSearchComponent implements OnInit {
    districts: district[];
    selectedDistrict: district;

    constructor(private districtService: districtService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getDistricts();
    }

    getDistricts() {
        return this.districtService.getDistricts().then(districts => this.districts = districts);
    }

    selectDistrict(district: district) {
        this.selectedDistrict = district;
    }
}
```

view.search.component.html

```
<select class="search-select">
    <option *ngFor="let district of districts" (click)="selectDistrict(district)">
        {{ district.name }}
    </option>
</select>

<select class="search-select">
    <option *ngFor="let city of selectedDistrict.cities ">
        {{ city.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very few people know that Angular2 supports elvis operator (i.e. ?) in templates which is extremely useful for asynchronous data streams. For that, you have to update the template as,

```
<select class="search-select">
    <option *ngFor="let city of selectedDistrict?.cities ">
        {{ city.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: what does it do exactly?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you wanted to avoid `Cannot read property 'cities' of undefined` error especially when the data arrives asynchronously after some time. So the elvis operator does not read `cities` if `selectedDistrict` object is undefined/null and prevents the error from happening. Is not it solving your problem?

Comment: I thought about another solution, I did *ngIf="selectedDistrict" which solved my problem. Your solution looks cleaner. I'll check it out

Comment: Yeah. Note that `ngIf` will remove the DOM first and add it back later which is unnecessary. Not at all ideal if your DOM is huge and complex.

Comment: Thank you! your solution is Epic and much more cooler than mine! :P

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize your `selectedDistrict: district;`

```
selectedDistrict: district = {};
```

also for selecting an option I don't think this is a good idea `(click)="selectDistrict(district)"` because you could theoretically use the keyboard/arrows to select an item

so you should use the `onchange` event

```
<select (change)="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);">
```

Comment: Well now I don't get any error at the start, but I think that something is wrong when I do `(click)="selectDistrict(district)"` because I added to my html this code: `{{ selectedArea | json }}` and it was still empty even when I clicked on a district.

Comment: I don't know why, but I don't get any alert. What am I missing?

Comment: It is, but your answer is problematic because you can't make an empty object, It's not an instance of my District.

Answer (score 0):

try to initialize the districts: district[]; array
you can do that like:

```
districts = [];
```

the problem is that you are trying to access city property of an uninitialized object. you need to make sure that you districts objects are initialized.

for example using new

```
this.selectedDistrict = new District();
```

or

```
district = {  "id": 5,
  "name": "A district",
  "cities": [
    {
      "id": 59,
      "name": "City 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 60,
      "name": "City 2"
    }
  ]}
```

also in this code

```
<select class="search-select">
    <option *ngFor="let district of districts" (click)="selectDistrict(district)">
        {{ district.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

make sure that selectDistrict is called correctly

Comment: This is a problematic approach. I found a solution. I just had to do *ngIf="selectedDistrict".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing my `selectedDistrict`, I just had to add *ngIf="selectedDistrict" to my `select` element.